# Odoo v9 workflow

Tags: workflow, odoo-9, erp

Can please somebody help me to proceed further with Odoo 9 - 
I have to design a solution using Odoo inventory and BOM module where we get few inputs from clients and based on client requirement , BOM will be prepared using different selections from inventory module . What should be the appropriate approach please ?

I have past experience in SAP not in Odoo .
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

With the hope that with this you will get the solution for your dilemma regarding the BOM and inventory.

### Step 1 Install the MRP module

For the **Bill of Material**, configuration  You have to install the **MRP module** in the odoo V9.

After installing the MRP module you will found the following few changes

- Manufacturing menu
- Manufacturing >> Product >> Bill of material
- & Button in the product for the BOM.

As shown in below image.

[image: Create-Product-Config-BOM-1]

### Step 2 Crete Product

Now as per your client requirement you can create the main product with respective Bill of material (which is used in manufacturing or building the main product as per the client requirements.).
There are mainly two possible cases are there

1. Manufacturing the with no product variant and
2. Manufacturing product with variant

**CASE 1 Product with no variant**

For this, no special action are required from our side. Default odoo assume all the Product with no variant.

**Case 2 Product with variant**

To configure the product with the variant, **Go to Inventory >> Configuration >> Setting  >> Select Product Variant**

[image: Create-Product-Config-BOM-with-varient]

after config of the variant feature, you will find the new Variant menu in the product and Example is shown in below Image

[image: Create-Product-Config-BOM-with-varient-1]

### Step 3 Configure the Bill of Material

Click on the button **'Bill of the Material'** visible in the product.

**Note:**

1. There is 0, till we have not set any bill of the material.
2. If you have not created the subsidiary product prior then also here
   odoo will provide the facility to create the new product for the BOM

Here select the Quantity you to want to manufacture and the
Bill of material (which is used in manufacturing or building the main product as per the client requirements.).

[image: Create-Product-Config-BOM-2]

and save it now your product is ready with the bill of material configuration.

Might be this help you. still, if you have any question comment here I will try my best to help you.